# grub is showing three error lines before menu displays

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

No luck googling; I see three lines before menu displays:

```
error: `/boot/` not found
error: no such device `/.disk/info`
error: no such device `/.disk/mini-info`
```

Not positive about the third line...

Then the expected grub menu comes up. This is a Ubuntu 20.04 install so probably Grub 2.04; fresh install of ESP partition on external SSD via USB 3.0 ... secure boot, if that helps (I ran MOKUTIL after install).

Probably not worth the effort to troubleshoot (and Grub doesn't seem to log anywhere) but maybe someone has seen this string of messages?

Interestingly, the UEFI boot menu in firmware (Lenovo ideapad 5 pro) that I use to launch the external USB SSD labels that boot environment "Linpus Lite" rather than "Ubuntu"? I had a look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/9pjpok/noob_question_ubuntu_bootable_usb_shows_as_linpus/) article to see if I was looking at a firmware, or perhaps something missing on /dev/nvme0n1p1 that the grub on /dev/sda was griping about. Here's a snippet from that post on reddit:

> I recall having this happen on one computer; I think in my case, the
> UEFI bootloader firmware was programmed to display any Linux distro as
> that title.
>
> In that case, it wasn't a problem.

Comment: That it works after errors is strange. Is UEFI not finding first entry & then booting second entry in UEFI boot list? May be best to see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  With external drive, you normally can only use the Advanced Mode to make repairs.

Comment: I may, if it ever seems worth the effort, post my bootinfo. However, see the revised/added info above. No, the expected entry is highlighted and comes up correctly once the grub menu is reached.

Comment: [link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mg7Bfcmj3t/) to bootinfo.

Comment: Any idea how to do this (from the bootinfo file)?

Please do not forget to **make your UEFI firmware boot on the** The OS now in use - Ubuntu 21.10 CurrentSession entry (sda1/efi/****/shim****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !

Answer (score 0):

Boot-repair using a live USB Lubuntu 21.10 (same version as the desired boot image) solved the issue for me. It installed shimx64.efi which wasn't there previously, using the advanced options to wipe clean existing GRUB config, I did leave grub version alone rather than advancing to 22.04 (which I knew would probably have issues running os-prober). I did notice some grumbling about not being able to access TPM while it was loading; assuming this is Lenovo security to keep the boot environment secure.